# Logout from a webview to flutter

Tags: api, rest, flutter, dart, webview

```html
I/chromium( 4243): [INFO:CONSOLE(34)] "Uncaught TypeError: JSReceiver.Disconnect is not a function", source: https://myUrl......
```

I'm using a webview with flutter and I'd like to interact with a function javascript inside of webview and send it to flutter.In other term I would like to get disconnected from the webview.

in my web view I am using

```js
<div class="menuopt" onclick="JSReceiver.Disconnect();">Logout</div>
```

What I've tried so far in flutter:

```html
WebView(
                      initialUrl:
                          'https://www.url/insert.html?token=$token&id_user=$id',
                      javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                      onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
                        _controler.complete(webViewController);
                      },
                      javascriptChannels: Set.from([
                        JavascriptChannel(
                            name: 'JSReceiver',
                            onMessageReceived: (JavascriptMessage message) {
                              Disconect(){
                              sharedPreferences.clear();
                              Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => LoginPage()), (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
                              print("disconnect");
                            }}
                            )
                      ]),

                    );
```

Comment: Hi, which web view plugin are you using? Can you elaborate what's the behaviour of your code and what's the desired behaviour?

Comment: Him I am using webview flutter "package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart". I want  my function to forward me to the login page. But instead this is what I get after clicking on the logout button in my webview: I/chromium( 4243): [INFO:CONSOLE(34)] "Uncaught TypeError: JSReceiver.Disconnect is not a function", source: https://

Answer (score 0):

even though it's not clear to me the syntax of `Disconnect(){...}`, I think that the correct implementation of this should be something like this:

```
WebView(
  initialUrl:
      'https://www.url/insert.html?token=$token&id_user=$id',
  javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
  onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
    _controler.complete(webViewController);
  },
  javascriptChannels: Set.from(
    [
      JavascriptChannel(
          name: 'JSReceiver',
          onMessageReceived: (JavascriptMessage message) {
            if (message == "disconnect"){
            sharedPreferences.clear();
            Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => LoginPage()), 
              (Route<dynamic> route) => false,
            );
            print("disconnect");
          }
        }
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

and, from JavaScript side, you do:

```
JsReceiver.postMessage('disconnect');
```

Although I've never used [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) (I've used [flutter_webview_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin)) and there's no explicit documentation, my answer is based on:

- [this example from their repo](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/2fb8bf023a43ef93b2f372f277fa16399d79b744/packages/webview_flutter/example/lib/main.dart#L84)
- [this comment on the JavaScript channels feature request](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24837#issuecomment-493270398)
- the fact that the process should be similar to the one in [the process in flutter_webview_plugin](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_webview_plugin/blob/4862bd987cf8ce6695d8d280ab407d57e5ae30f0/example/lib/main.dart#L13)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, thank you for ur response .Unfortunately I am unable to change JavaScript code in the web view.As for the plugin plz let me know if the flutter_webview_plugin was a better choice. It still doesn't recognize the function on javascript    "<div class="menuopt" onclick="JSReceiver.Disconnect();">Logout</div>"

Comment: unfortunately you need to change the JavaScript code, because the JSReceiver is a channel and that channel has the standard method postMessage, and Disconnect is not a method of the channel object. As far as I know this is how js channels work. And, regarding the better choice, I cannot answer that because I have no experience with webview_flutter. Apparently the teams are working together and they have similar functionalities, so I'd stick with the one you know!